# Parse git config --list

Tags: git, config

I want to parse `git config --list`.

First I think I can parse this to object separated between dot. E.g.

```
color.ui=auto
branch.master.remote=upstream
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
# => { 
    core: { ui: auto },
    branch: { master: { remote: upstream, merge: refs/heads/master }}
}
```

But sometimes name has dot :(

I want to do below:

```
url.git@gist.github.com:.pushinsteadof=https://gist.github.com/
branch.chore/foo.bar.baz.remote=upstream
branch.chore/foo.bar.baz.merge=refs/heads/master
# => {
    url: { git@gist.github.com: { pushinsteadof: https://gist.github.com/ } },
    branch: { chore/foo.bar.baz: { remote: upstream, merge: refs/heads/master } }
}
```

How to achieve this?
Should I re-implement git-config https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#FILES and include section?
I want to change a section separator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I see from the [`git config` man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config), the key first and last element have not dots in them.

So in `branch.chore/foo.bar.baz.remote`, you can search for the first '.' and last '.' (giving you `branch` and `remote`). Everything in the middle is one key name.